# prevent query to captcha generator from YSlow

Tags: php, session, captcha, yslow

i have a pretty simple captcha, something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function randomText($length) {
        $pattern = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++) {
            $key .= $pattern{rand(0,35)};
        }
        return $key;
    }
    $textCaptcha=randomText(8);
    $_SESSION['tmptxt'] = $textCaptcha;
    $captcha = imagecreatefromgif("bgcaptcha.gif");
    $colText = imagecolorallocate($captcha, 0, 0, 0);
    imagestring($captcha, 5, 16, 7, $textCaptcha, $colText);

    header("Content-type: image/gif");
    imagegif($captcha);
?>
```

the problem is that if the user have YSlow installed, the image is query 2 times, so, the captcha is re-generated and never match with the one inserted by the user.

i saw that is only query a second time if i pass the content-type header as gif, if i print it as a normal php, this doesn't happen.

someone have any clue about this? how i can prevent it or identify that the second query is made by YSlow, to do not generate the captcha again.

Regards,
Shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YSlow does request the page components when run, so it sounds like your problem is cases where the user has YSlow installed **and** it's set to run automatically at each page load.

The best solution may be to adjust your captcha code to not recreate new values within the same session, or if it does to make sure the session variable matches the image sent.

But to your original question about detecting the second query made by YSlow, it's possible if you look at the HTTP headers received.

I just ran a test and found these headers sent with the YSlow request. The User-Agent is set to match the browser (Firefox in my case), but you could check for the presence of `X-YQL-Depth` as a signal. (YSlow uses [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql) for all of its requests.)

```
Array
(
    [Client-IP] => 1.2.3.4
    [X-Forwarded-For] => 1.2.3.4,  5.6.7.8
    [X-YQL-Depth] => 1
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip
    [Host] => www.example.com
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Via] => HTTP/1.1 htproxy1.ops.sp1.yahoo.net[D1832930] (YahooTrafficServer/1.19.5 [uScM])
)
```